# How to pass a custom type value to pgx query in Go

Tags: sql, go, pgx

I have a custom type:

```golang
type CustomData struct{
    data string
}
```

and I want to pass it as a string parameter to an SQL query

```golang
d := CustomData{data: "help, i need somebody"}

_, err := tx.Exec(ctx, `INSERT INTO tab (data) VALUES ($1)`, d)
```

I get an error

```
failed to encode args[0]: unable to encode CustomData{data: "help, i need somebody"} into text format for varchar (OID 1043): cannot find encode plan
```

Which interface should `CustomData` implement to be unmarshalled as a string?

---

**UPDATE**

I implemented `pgtype.TextValuer` interface as @Adrian wrote in the comment.

```golang
func (d *CustomData) TextValue() (pgtype.Text, error) {
    return pgtype.Text{
        String: d.data,
        Valid:  true,
    }, nil
}
```

Unfortunately it didn't change an error message.

Comment: you can just stringfy your data before insert.

Comment: You've implemented `TextValue` on `*CustomData`, but you're passing `CustomData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Per the package docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v5#hdr-PostgreSQL_Data_Types):

> pgx uses the pgtype package to converting Go values to and from PostgreSQL values. It supports many PostgreSQL types directly and is customizable and extendable. User defined data types such as enums, domains, and composite types may require type registration. See that package's documentation for details.

[Per that package's documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v5@v5.4.3/pgtype#hdr-Extending_Existing_PostgreSQL_Type_Support):

> Generally, all Codecs will support interfaces that can be implemented to enable scanning and encoding. For example, PointCodec can use any Go type that implements the PointScanner and PointValuer interfaces. So rather than use pgtype.Point and application can directly use its own point type with pgtype as long as it implements those interfaces.

Meaning you can implement [pgtype.TextScanner](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v5@v5.4.3/pgtype#TextScanner) and [pgtype.TextValuer](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v5@v5.4.3/pgtype#TextValuer) on any type to create the behavior of a string value.

Comment: please see an update